Again Antiforgery token validation failed. The antiforgery token could not be decrypted
I'm setting Antiforgy for .net+Angular app.
I declare settings for session
builder.Services.AddSession(options => {
  options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
  options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
  options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
  options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
  options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
});

I declare DataProtection
builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"./keys"))
    .UseCryptographicAlgorithms(new AuthenticatedEncryptorConfiguration {
      EncryptionAlgorithm = EncryptionAlgorithm.AES_256_CBC,
      ValidationAlgorithm = ValidationAlgorithm.HMACSHA256
    })
    .SetApplicationName("BudgetTracker")
    .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(14));

I add attribute for controllers
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options => {
  options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
});

I declare Antifogery settings
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(options => {
  options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
  options.Cookie.Name = "XSRF-TOKEN";
  options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
  options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
  options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
  options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(14);
  options.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = false;
  options.FormFieldName = "AntiforgeryField";
});

I use middleware for Antifogery
app.UseMiddleware<AntiForgeryMiddleware>();

This is the code of middleware:
  public class AntiForgeryMiddleware {
    private readonly IAntiforgery _antiforgery;
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger<TokenValidationMiddleware> _logger;

    public AntiForgeryMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IAntiforgery antiforgery, ILogger<TokenValidationMiddleware> logger) {
      _next = next;
      _antiforgery = antiforgery;
      _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context) {
      try {
        if (string.Equals(context.Request.Path.Value, "/session/csrf", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
          var token = _antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context).RequestToken;
          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token)) {
            context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", token, new CookieOptions {
              HttpOnly = false,
              Secure = true,
              SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
              Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(14)
            });
          }
          _logger.LogInformation($"Generated XSRF-TOKEN: {token}");
        }

      } catch (Exception ex) {
        _logger.LogError(new EventId(), ex, ex.Message);
        throw;
      }

      await _next(context);
    }
  }

The key file in /keys is created. I see X-XSRF-TOKEN in headers and in session. I have interceptor in Angular:
intercept(request: HttpRequest\<any\>, next: HttpHandler): Observable\<HttpEvent\<any\>\> {
let token = this.tokenExtractor.getToken();
let permitted = this.findByActionName(request.method, this.actions);
let forbidden = this.findByActionName(request.method, this.forbiddenActions);;

    if (permitted !== undefined && forbidden === undefined && token !== null) {   
      request = request.clone({ setHeaders: { "X-XSRF-TOKEN": token }, withCredentials: true });
    }
    return next.handle(request);

}

private findByActionName(name: string, actions: string\[\]): string | undefined {
  return actions.find(action =\> action.toLocaleLowerCase() === name.toLocaleLowerCase());
  }
}

I can see logs on server:
info: webapi.Middlewares.AntiForgeryTokenLoggingMiddleware[0]
      Request XSRF-TOKEN: cece034d-b5a2-4042-a884-c4aa9399436b
info: webapi.Middlewares.AntiForgeryTokenLoggingMiddleware[0]
      Request X-XSRF-TOKEN: cece034d-b5a2-4042-a884-c4aa9399436b

But I get error:
[19:02:46 INF] Antiforgery token validation failed. The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.
 ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The provided payload cannot be decrypted because it was not protected with this protection provider. 

I've spend 3 days to find solution. Changed different setting, googled for different solution, I used code from microsoft, used chartgpt, but nothing helps. Could you please explain, what is wrong?
Thanks!

looks like you're doing too much on the backend and frontend.  Let ASP.NET take care of encrypting/decrypting.   I'll post the code I use... (btw, it can be difficult to test this locally if cross-site...)  Also see here for ASP.NET side (that's pretty much all you need): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-8.0#generate-antiforgery-tokens-with-iantiforgery

Here's what I do in case it helps:
In program.cs on ASP.NET side:
    builder.Services.AddMvc(options =>
  {
      options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
      //I use AddMvc 'cause I'm on .NET6, and AddControllers() does not have antiforgery in that version.
  }); 

builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
{
    options.HeaderName = "Xsrf-Token";

});
 var antiforgery = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IAntiforgery>();
    app.Use((context, next) =>
    {
        var requestPath = context.Request.Path.Value;
        var tokenSet = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
        context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokenSet.RequestToken!,
        new CookieOptions { HttpOnly = false });
        return next(context);
    });

On Angular side:
In "imports" section of app.module.ts file:
 HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
   cookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
   headerName: 'XSRF-TOKEN'
 })


notice I leave the cooke name alone in ASP.NET backend.  You can let ASP.NET take care of setting that... it's an httponly cookie that will be passed back and forth without Angular needing to know of it.  The "XSRF-TOKEN" is the non-httponly cookie that will be read by Angular (set from the previous GET) and sent along as "XSRF-TOKEN" header.

Btw, ASP.NET doesn't care about the case of incoming header or parameter names.   (I know this line looks odd: options.HeaderName = "Xsrf-Token", but could be any case...)  While debugging locally I had to turn off anti-forgery because I was cross-site and not secure.  ASP.NET sets cookies secure, same-site by default.... it also prevents framing.

The other caveat which tripped me up for a bit is that HttpClientXsrfModule won't work with absolute paths.  (Your baseURL should be just ".")

Unfortunately, it did not help. Error is the same.

Thanks for your help. Yout right, I'de made to much. I started to do it like you said and I've found a reason of mistake. I generated token 2 times - with middleware and controller. I've deleted middleware, applied your settings and it works! I'm so happy!
