ASP.NET Core Web API : AntiforgeryValidationException: The required antiforgery cookie ".AspNetCore.Antiforgery.mirJ4ZzQPmw" is not present
We are doing some migration from old .NET framework to .NET Core and I need to add antiforgery token handling.
In my ASP.NET Core 8 Web API, I configured and added a middleware:
public const string ANTIFORGEY_TOKEN_HEADER_NAME = "__RequestVerificationToken";

    public static void ConfigureAntiforgeryToken(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
        {
            // Set Cookie properties using CookieBuilder properties
            options.FormFieldName = "AntiforgeryToken";
            options.HeaderName = GeneralAppConstants.ANTIFORGEY_TOKEN_HEADER_NAME;
            options.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = false;
        });
    }

public class AntiforgeryTokenMiddleware(IAntiforgery antiforgery) : IMiddleware
{
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        if (!HttpMethods.IsPost(context.Request.Method))
        {
            await next(context);
        }
        else
        {
            var executingEnpoint = context.GetEndpoint();
            var attributes = executingEnpoint.Metadata.OfType<ValidateJsonAntiForgeryTokenAttribute>();

            if (attributes?.Any() ?? false)
            {
                await antiforgery.ValidateRequestAsync(context);
            }
        }
    }
}

When I hit my endpoint with request where I set the header with:
__RequestVerificationToken: some token

I got the following error

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The required antiforgery cookie ".AspNetCore.Antiforgery.mirJ4ZzQPmw" is not present.

Then I tried to add another middleware that will add a XSRF-TOKEN cookie:
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
{
    var tokenSet = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
    context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokenSet.RequestToken!, new CookieOptions { HttpOnly = false });
}

But I get the same error.
I can see in the request header the values:
Set-Cookie: some token

I tried to copy it to the Insomnia and test it, but always the same error.
Thanks

same-site will be strict for that cookie... not sure if that's an issue here or not, but you should simplify this... you won't need to build a custom middleware, just put everything in program.cs.  You won't need to use a header value at all unless you are using an SPA for front end and are only returning raw data like JSON from backend... if so, see my answer here for an example of how to setup asp.net to use header: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78497078/again-antiforgery-token-validation-failed-the-antiforgery-token-could-not-be-de/78497501#78497501

My pain is that the old MVC is still functioning as an frontend, and the forms are still there as an MVC forms, where some of them has the Antiforgery token in them.

That'll be very easy.  Just insert the anti-forgery tokens in the forms.  Everything's already setup for that flow.  (There will be a hidden field in the form... no need to set a non-httponly cookie, or send token in a custom header.)  What you are trying to do now is for backends that do not output html.

If I understood you correctly, then you are saying that I just need only the validation part and all other part can be removed?!
Will it validate correctly because they are not on the same domain?!

ASP.NET is already setup to validate the anti-forgery token.  You'd insert that into the form in the .cshtml file.  The HTML Helper for @BeginForm does that automatically.... otherwise use @Html.AntiForgeryToken().  This will not work cross-domain as the cookie that'll be checked against the hidden field is set as same-site: strict.  You are trying to prevent cross-domain requests so that an attacker can't make a request on behalf of your user(s).  Likewise, if you use the non-httponly technique to read and then send as a custom header, you can't read that cookie cross-domain.
